# TeamCity is locking my windows account out when building

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity but have set up version 8.0.5.  I am running it on a Windows 2008 R2 server and TeamCity is running as a service.  I have configured the authentication to connect to the domain (which all works correctly)

I have created a project which connects to TFS to get the source code and compile it when the source code has changed.

The builds all work fine however, every time the build completes my windows account gets locked out (even if I did not trigger the build).  This becomes increasingly annoying as other people are working on this project.

The TeamCity service does not use my account (it uses a service account) and the service account is used to get the code from TFS.  When I view the project configurations, my account is not shown anywhere.

I have checked all of the configuration files and non of them are using my account credentials.

I have looked at the log files and I can't see anything there to indicate that my account is locked.  However the TeamCity server is the server that is locking my account and it is happening when a build is completed.

As I'm still fairly new to TFS please can someone help me to establish why TeamCity could be locking out my account?

Thanks.

Comment: Easy question: Why are you using Teamcity for automated builds over team build, which is bundled with TFS and works perfectly?

Comment: We had issues with TFS build locking services on the build machine requiring us to login to the server and kill a process (I forget which process).  TeamCity is much, much easier better for us.  I wouldn't go back to TFS now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing two things:

1)  The TFS login account was previously using my login credentials, I removed these (to force it to use the service account).

This didn't actually resolve the issue.
2)  Rebooting the TeamCity server seemed to resolve the problem (with the step above).